# How to do a NotEqual to in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have an enumeration of type int in my entity, UserStatus.

I want to get all users where the UserStatus <> Cancelled.

So:

```
Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(User))
.Add(Expression.Eq("UserStatus", (int)UserStatus.Cancelled)
.UniqueResult<User>();
```

**The above is fore equal, I need to get not equal.**

Answer (score 45, accepted):

With thanks to Alex use this for NH2 and up:

```
Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(User))
.Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("UserStatus", (int)UserStatus.Cancelled))
.UniqueResult<User>();
```

For older Versions this would be:

```
Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(User))
.Add(Expression.Not(Expression.Eq("UserStatus", (int)UserStatus.Cancelled))
.UniqueResult<User>();
```

Comment: `Expression` is semi-deprecated.  Replace its use with `Restrictions`

Answer (score 3):

```
.Add(!Restrictions.Eq(propertyName, value));
```

Comment: this was mapped to [ ... and not (propertyName = ?) ] in my case and worked with Oracle